# Improper linking, Function undefined, eclipse GCC library path

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, linker

I am using eclipse on debian, GCC compiler and I have followed the instructions to install the libsocket library.

My code is as follows:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <libsocket/libinetsocket.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;

    sockfd = create_inet_server_socket("0.0.0.0", 5671, LIBSOCKET_TCP, LIBSOCKET_IPv4, SOCK_NONBLOCK);
```

and so on and so forth.

My problem is as follows:

When I build the program, I get

> undefined reference to 'create_inet_server_socket' main.c

So I read, on this very site, that I not only need to include the header file, I also need to tell gcc about the .so file... Sheesh...

So I went to project>properties>c/c++ general>paths and symbols where I added a "library" reference to the `libsocket.so` file in `usr/lib` folder.

I then got this:

> cannot find -l/usr/lib/libsocket.so    HomeWatch Server

And, well, now i'm stuck...

the `libinetsocket.h` is in `usr/include/libsocket`
the `libsocket.so` is in `usr/lib`

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Try just `socket`. That is, the command line should end up containing `-lsocket`. That would look for `libsocket.so` in the standard library directories.

Comment: That worked! I have no idea why though... why would simply typing socket tell it to search for libsocket.so? Some kind of wildacard??

Comment: I've never used eclipse but according to the error message it generates `-lwhatever`. And that tells the linker to search for a library by prepending `lib` to the name and trying various suffixes (`.a`, `.so`) (this is probably documented somewhere in `info gcc` or `info ld`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link to the library using the `-l` flag in the `gcc` compiler. This works because the library you want, `libsocket.so`, is defined in the default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shared environment variable (defaults to `/usr/lib`). The `-l` flag works by taking the string following it then adding `lib` before the string and `.so` after then navigates to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find it.

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH/libsocket.so
```

It is worth noting here that if you ever have a library you would like to link that is in a different directory than the default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` change it by running the following command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Or you can link it inline by first defining `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using the `-L` flag then using `-l` to link the library.

```
gcc -L/path/to/lib -lyourLib yourProgram.c -o yourProgram
```

**Example**

`/home/customLibraries/libFastMath.so` could be linked the following ways:

```
gcc -L/home/customLibraries -lFastMath yourProgram.c -o yourProgram
```

*OR*

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/customLibraries:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gcc -lFastMath yourProgram.c -o yourProgram
```

You can read more about how `gcc` handles linking [here](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_C_libraries.html).